# No rule to make target `main.c', needed by `main.o'. Stop

Tags: c, unix, makefile, program-entry-point

I am trying to make a Makefile and I am getting errors:

make: *** No rule to make target main.c, needed by main.o.  Stop.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error, or even suggest a fix if possible, Thank you.

```
TARGET =    example

SRC_FILES = \
Makefile \
README \
a.c \
a.h \
b.c \
b.h \
main.c

OBJS = \
  main.o \
  a.o \
  b.o


CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99


(TARGET):       $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


$(TARGET):      $(TARGET).html $(TARGET).pdf 

$(TARGET).html:     $(TARGET).umt
        $(UMT) $< >$@

$(TARGET).pdf:      $(TARGET).html
        $(HTML2PS) -N 0 -n $(TARGET).html > $(TARGET).ps
        $(PS2PDF) $(TARGET).ps 
        rm -f $(TARGET).ps


clean:
        rm -f $(TARGET).html $(TARGET).pdf


a.o:        a.c a.h
b.o:        b.c b.h
main.o:     main.c a.h b.h
```

Comment: You get this error because there is no `main.c` in your source directory, nor any other file make knows how to convert to `main.o`. Should there be one? ATM your makefile expects being able to make the objects `main.o`, `a.o` and `b.o`.

Comment: if this is an old-line unix OS you're using, recall that for some OSs,  elements of targets have to be indented with real TAB chars, not spaces. I think the error msgs would be different, but worth dbl-chking. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Deduplicator already explained why you are getting this error. Suggested fix: Provide a `main.c`, or change the file names in the make file to the names of the files you have (`example.c` maybe).